# css3 image crossfade (no javascript)

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm pretty sure it's possible to do a css only image crossfade using the new css animation features. My requirements are that it should work for arbitrary number of images without javascript.

Does anyone know how it's done?

How I'm starting off:

```
img(src='img1.png')
img(src='img2.png')
img(src='img3.png')
img(src='img4.png')
```

Next all the images are set to stack on top of each other with the first one showing:

```
img
  opacity 0
  transition 1s
  position absolute

  &:first-child
    opacity 100
```

Now how do I go through each image?

Edit: Seems impossible. Requires javascript.

Comment: Quick demo: crossfade on hover http://jsfiddle.net/e1z034uy/

Answer (score 8):

This article is the best I've seen for doing an effect like this.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

They use spans, animation and the :nth-child property to achieve a crossfade between the background images. Pretty awesome.

```
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}


    .cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg)
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
    animation-delay: 30s;
}

.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
```

Comment: This is the same thing as Michael Robinson's answer.

Comment: The problem with that tutorial is that it's not a true dissolve. If your background color is not white or if your text and background colors are the same then there are some visual shortcomings.

Answer (score 6):

Use keyframes, outlined in this article: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3

Comment: is arbitrary number of images impossible? It seems as if you need to set the number. Also the example doesn't loop around to the first after the animation is complete.

Comment: @Harry: It loops for me - I guess because of `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Comment: @MichaelRobinson: Sorry but I can't see where the total images has been set in that example.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at the second half of demo 3. The first half uses only 2 images, it seems like only 2 images could work. The second half uses 4 images but they explicitly define 4 in the css.

Comment: I've decided that this is still probably the best answer. I can use javascript to set the number of files since pure css seems impossible. Thanks.