# Multiple image cross fading in CSS - without (java) script

Tags: css

Is it possible to cross fade 5 images in CSS, without using java script? I have found a similar question: 
[css3 image crossfade (no javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540906/css3-image-crossfade-no-javascript) , however, it has only the CSS code snippet; which I tried, but could not get it working. I'm new to CSS, so could not link the CSS mentioned in the above page to my following HTML:

```
  <div id= "crossfade">
     <img class = "cone" src = "1.png" alt = "png">
     <img class = "ctwo" src = "2.png" alt = "png">
     <img class = "cthree" src = "3.png" alt = "png">
     <img class = "cfour" src = "4.png" alt = "png">
     <img class = "cfive" src = "5.png" alt = "png">
  </div>
```

Comment: Provide a test case. (on jsfiddle for instance.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can easily be done with CSS3 if you know how many images you have.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hajmd/

```
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s; 
}
```

The "30s" at "*-webkit-animation: imageAnimation **30s** linear **infinite** 0s;*" tells that the animation for each image will last 30 seconds in infinete number of times.

```
#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  { 
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) { 
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) { 
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) { 
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you referenced should work for you for the example you referenced.  However please note that CSS3 is not supported on all browsers (Such as IE8 and IE7) and therefore will not work in those browsers.

Comment: Probably you didn't read my post clearly. I could not find how to link that example to my above HTML. I'm using Chrome version 24.