# CSS Multiple Image Crossfade

Tags: css, image, animation, fade

I've been searching for a few hours for the answer to this and I've still not come up with anything that really works!

I have a `div` that contains 3 `img` elements. I want to fade each to the next in an infinite loop.

I know it's likely to include animations but I can't understand exactly how the work and what bits I need to change to adapt the fading to what I require.

Thanks for any help guys! I really appreciate this, just trying to figure this out as I've used .gifs before and I feel it's time to move on!

Just in case you do want the code:

```
    <div id="showcase">
        <img src="../images/showcase/iphone2.png" width="175" height="202" />
        <img src="../images/showcase/m4.png" width="175" height="202" />
        <img src="../images/showcase/alloy.png" width="175" height="202" />
    </div>
```

As I said, I've looked at numerous examples and I'm just looking for a basic fade from one to the other using CSS. I would prefer not to use JavaScript.

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: "I would prefer not to use JavaScript." Any particular reason for this?

Comment: I believe it is entirely possible in CSS and as such I would like to learn this way as well as the JS possibility.

I have searched several websites and attempted their ways but it's more the problem that I can't get my head around how animations work in CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicat : [Multiple image cross fading in CSS - without (java) script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using css animations:
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Note: 
This will not work with non css3 browsers.

Comment: Thanks this helped, I managed to finally get it right! Cheers!

Comment: And still the website gives good explanation about the topic.