# fading between background images using only html/css/js

Tags: html, css, background, fade, intervals

I have 6 images of different sizes that I need to load into a single fading background. I want the first image to load when the page is opened, and in X amount of seconds fade directly into a second image (no white or black transparency in the transition) and then loop when it gets to the end. I've found hundreds of examples for this but none seem to work properly for what I need it to do. Is there a way I can do it solely with html/css or is it too complex for that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid it's to complex to only use html and css, however, you can do it with javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide examples of your code and give specifics as to what isn't working?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like something that is possible with Css3 Animations.  But I'll have to look into it.  Honestly, it would just be better to use JS.

Comment: I've searched google for a while for an answer and a lot of them do incorporate JS but when I go to view the page and see if it works it doesnt, it's just all my images crammed together on the page and theres no fading/animation/changing whatsoever. I've tried most things you'll find by doing a google search.


I want to do this pretty much:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index.html

Comment: @ThePhard Javascript or jQuery? If it is jQuery then you need to link your website to the jQuery library.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with pure css, may not be the safest bet due to browser limitations of [css3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

What I am doing is using a `keyframe` to change between the pictures with an infinite loop on it.

Break down of the css animation style:

`-webkit(1)-animation: slides(2) 15s(3) linear infinite(4);`

1. Browser prefix
2. keyframes name
3. how long the animation is
4. Informs the animation to loop once completed.

This is the css and the `keyframe`:

```
.mainCont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://forestry.ky.gov/Kentuckysstateforests/PublishingImages/TygartsStateForest.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    animation: slides 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slides 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: slides 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: slides 15s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: slides 15s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slides {
    from {
        background: url("http://forestry.ky.gov/Kentuckysstateforests/PublishingImages/TygartsStateForest.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    20% {
        background: url("http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Falling-asleep-forest.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    40% {
        background: url("http://forestry.ky.gov/Kentuckysstateforests/PublishingImages/TygartsStateForest.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    60% {
        background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Epping_Forest_Centenary_Walk_2_-_Sept_2008.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    80% {
        background: url("http://foundwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/forest-tree-sun-ray-light-spruce.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    to {
        background: url("http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130516163359/creepypasta/images/c/c5/Green-forest-wallpaper.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo-remove show in url to see code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp2Q9/1/show/)

Comment: Nice Solution Josh!  I was going a different a route.  Trying to add 4 different Animations.  Having Multiple Background Images.  Each Fading out and Fading in over a certain time period.

Comment: @AndrewIce Thank you! I was just putting something together quickly. If you add more keyframes to the animation you could achieve what you want. One keyframe for the fading in and out, then a keyframe for the transition effect.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I plug in my necessary information. I just get white, so i guess it's not loading it properly. I pretty much copy and pasted this to sample it but didn't get anything different.

Comment: I was able to achieve it just like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script

And then simply using the "z-index" to order the changing background and the leave the clickable link on top of it all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want fullscreen here and that you're ok with Javascript (since it's mentioned in the title), let's say you have two divs container with the following css:

```
.bg {
    position   : fixed;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    opacity    : 0;
    transition : opacity .8s ease-out; // not adding browser specifics for clarity sake
    background : #FFF url(photo.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.active {
  opacity      : 1;
}
```

then in you js you can simply do:

```
var images = ["photo_1.jpg", "photo_2.png", "photo_3.gif","photo4.jpg"]
  , delay  = 3000  // 3 seconds
  , pointer= 0
  , xfade  = function() {
         var selectedBg = $('.bg:not(.active)')
           , image      = images[pointer%images.length];

         $('.bg.active').removeClass('active');
         selectedBg.css({'backgroundImage':"url("+image+")"}).addClass('active');
         pointer += 1;
    }

setInterval(xfade, delay);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F426j/1/