# Image fit size of parent div

Tags: html, css, image, size

I got the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="crossfade">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css (copied from elsewhere [Multiple image cross fading in CSS - without (java) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script))

```
.container
{
width:100px;
 }
.crossfade > img { 
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     color: transparent;
     opacity: 0;
z-index: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s; 
 }

 .crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
-webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 6s;
-o-animation-delay: 6s;
-ms-animation-delay: 6s;
animation-delay: 6s; 
 }
 .crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
-moz-animation-delay: 12s;
-o-animation-delay: 12s;
-ms-animation-delay: 12s;
animation-delay: 12s; 
 }
 .crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
-moz-animation-delay: 18s;
-o-animation-delay: 18s;
-ms-animation-delay: 18s;
animation-delay: 18s; 
 }
 .crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
-moz-animation-delay: 24s;
-o-animation-delay: 24s;
-ms-animation-delay: 24s;
animation-delay: 24s; 
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
8% { opacity: 1;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
17% { opacity: 1 }
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
 }

 @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
8% { opacity: 1;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
17% { opacity: 1 }
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
 }

 @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
8% { opacity: 1;
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
17% { opacity: 1 }
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
 }

 @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
8% { opacity: 1;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
17% { opacity: 1 }
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
 }

 @keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% { opacity: 0;
animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
8% { opacity: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
17% { opacity: 1 }
25% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
 }
```

What I want is that the images are resized to the size of the container.

Comment: How should 5 images being 200x100 px fit inside a container which is 200x100 px?

Comment: There will be only 1 visible. Im trying to make a slider.

Comment: Okay, please update your question with that, as it matters. ... What should happen with an image that is higher than wider, like 200x400 px ...cropped, stretched, keep aspect ratio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, that deals with different image sizes and kept aspect ratio.

If you resize the browser window, it still plays nicely with all the images.

*Updated on request, using 1 `container`*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.slider .image {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0;
  animation: sliderimagefade 20s 0s infinite;
}

.slider .image:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.slider .image:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.slider .image:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
.slider .image:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.slider .image:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 16s;
}

@keyframes sliderimagefade {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1')">
    </div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/100/animals/2')">
    </div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/400/animals/3')">
    </div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4')">
    </div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/300/animals/5')">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have a small problem. My container contains a lot of data. Do I have to copy those 5 times?

Comment: Could u make the same with: Container, SmallContainer, image? Smallcontainer and image same size as container. And the images above each other.

Comment: @DennisV I updated, so now you can drop the `slider` into your `container` and have it running there.

Comment: The slider ain't the same size as my container.

Comment: @DennisV You can for example change `slider` to `position: relative;` and make it flow with your content, and as well set any size by just change the `width` and `height`

Comment: @DennisV Here is a fiddle demo for you, using your container from your question: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/vsf4nk7g/

Comment: @DennisV Thanks, and glad I could help

Comment: One more question, I added 2 images. How should i adjust the keyframes? The last picture is only visible for 1 sec. I adjusted the animation delay but i think i should adjust the keyframes too.

Comment: @DennisV When you add images you need to adjust the animation-duration, intervals and keyframe. Check my comments in this updated sample I made for you, with 7 images: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/vsf4nk7g/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fill container, you can use:

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

But this solution probably will not keep aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If your .container is 200px width and 100px height you will have the following ;

```
<body>
<div class="container" style="width:200px;height:100px;" >
    <div class="div2">
        <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1">
        <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2">
        <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3">
        <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4">
        <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5">
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you don't want to use inline css you will need to create a new file, for example style.css and then add a `<link>` to this file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="div2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/1">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/2">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/3">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/4">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/5">
    </div>
</div>
```

File style.css (should be in the same folder)

```
.container{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
.container .div2 img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```