# How to make the transition of keyframe images appear to be smooth

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a sequence of keyframes that displays seven different images. The images appear in a way that look unnatural. You can see the new image flash on the screen. I want this animation to appear in a way that it looks like it is one image that is simply making subtle changes.

I am attaching the keyframe sequence.

Does it have anything to do with how my keyframe percents are made up or what?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes think {
    0%, 30% {background-image: url("/images/think.png");}
    32%, 41% {background-image: url("/images/think22.png");}
    42%, 55% {background-image: url("/images/think3.png");}
    56%, 69% {background-image: url("/images/think4.png");}
    70%, 83% {background-image: url("/images/think5.png");}
    84%, 99% {background-image: url("/images/think6.png");}
    100% {background-image: url("/images/think7.png");}
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg0y4936/)

Comment: Do you still see the flash [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xg0y4936/1/)? It is better to not leave a gap between the keyframes as images don't transition or  change smoothly (atleast not cross-browser).

Comment: @Harry Yes, I still see the flash. It seems once it plays more than once it doesn't do the flash, but I'm sure that has to do with the cache. Upon first load it does it.

Comment: @Harry Any ideas on what I could do then?

Comment: Nope. Maybe you could preload the images before the animation starts but I wouldn't trust CSS with smooth transition of animations. I don't think it works well cross browser. It might be better for you to recreate that image using SVG and then animate it instead of a PNG.

Comment: Could you explain both in further detail. How could I preload the images and what would a SVG do?

Comment: Both are pretty broad to explain within the scope of an answer. You can find some info about preloading approaches in this page - https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/. For SVG, you can use some tool like Illustrator, create the image as a .svg file and animate it.

Comment: That link worked wonders! I don't have illustrator or I would have attempted doing it that way. Thanks for your help and feel free to answer this question. I will accept it.

Comment: Would there be anyway to replay only the 42% - 100% infinitely without looping through the entire keyframe set?

Comment: You're welcome @Becky. I will wait a while to see if you get any better answers other than a "No, this is the best" and if not, I will add this as answer. The other part can be done with multiple animatons. If you want, I can show that maybe in an answer. Give me sometime and I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for cross-fading of images or smooth transition of images from one state to another. It is not impossible but is not simple. You can do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script) but as you can see there, it is done with multiple images placed on top of each other and their opacity is animated instead of the background image itself.

The best bet would be to use frames as close to the previous one as possible and also to preload the images before the animation starts. These can help to minimize the flicker. [This](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) article discusses few approaches that can be used for pre-loading images. Alternately, you can also look at SVG to create the image and then animate it. It is far more easier to animate SVG than it is to animate images.

Coming to the other part of the question (which was, can frames from 42% to 100% alone be repeated without repeating the first 42%), it can be done by using two separate animations - one for the first part and the other for the second. The first animation should have only one iteration whereas the 2nd must have iteration count as infinite.

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: blue;
}

.think {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-animation-name: think, think2;
  animation-name: think, think2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3.28s, 4.72s;
  animation-duration: 3.28s, 4.72s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 3.28s; /* delay second so that it starts after 1st finishes */
  animation-delay: 0s, 3.28s; /* delay second so that it starts after 1st finishes */
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*min-height: 500px; min-width: 500px;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-size: 100% auto;*/
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes think {
  0%,
  74.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think.png");
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think22.png");
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes think2 {
  0%,
  19.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think3.png");
  }
  20%,
  39.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think4.png");
  }
  40%,
  59.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think5.png");
  }
  60%,
  79.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think6.png");
  }
  80%, 100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think7.png");
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes think {
  0%,
  74.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think.png");
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think22.png");
  }
}

@keyframes think2 {
  0%,
  19.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think3.png");
  }
  20%,
  39.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think4.png");
  }
  40%,
  59.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think5.png");
  }
  60%,
  79.99% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think6.png");
  }
  80%, 100% {
    background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/think7.png");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <div class="think"></div>
</div>
```

Ofcourse, the duration of the individual animations should be calculated based on frame percentages and the total animation duration used in the snippet in question. The second animation should also be **delayed** (by the same amount of time as duration of the first) to make sure that it doesn't interfere with the first animation and mess up things.

**Note:** If I remember correctly, Chrome can smoothly transition images from one state to another but it is not implemented in other browsers and hence it might not be a good idea to rely on that.

Comment: Thanks so much! Regarding the cross-compatibility, you are correct, Firefox and IE won't even display the images, but I believe I have another approach. This will all help out a bunch. Thanks!