# css image overlay transition

Tags: css, image, css-transitions

I'm trying to create an animated HTML/CSS banner add (HPU 300x600px max.80KB) made up of 4 images (4 stages smooth fade in transition from one to the next). To keep file size down I have made images 2, 3 & 4 partly transparent and the idea is that they fade in and overlay making the final image.

I have tried the approach in this answer: [Multiple image cross fading in CSS - without (java) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script) but the images disappear in each transition.

I have also tried Demo 3 (Demo with Multiple Images) here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3 but in the first loop all 4 images are shown.

What else can I try? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I develop banners in insane sizes too ;D

I have this example, I think is similar at yours
http://codepen.io/tarod_spj/pen/EyxVrg

In this cases I put the elements in absolute with diferents z-index like this:

```
.img1 {
  .animationSimple(animationIn forwards @timeImg1 ease @delayImg1 1);  z-index: 10;
}

.img2 {
  .animationSimple(animationIn forwards @delayImg2 ease @delayImg2 1); z-index: 20;
}
```

All of them starts with opacity: 0;
and the first img I usually put like background of the ad.

If you can explain more what you need maybe I can help you better