# How would I make this automatically cycle through?

Tags: javascript

SO I built this, with very simple javascript, just to allow a user to cycle through each feature bu clicking on the button. I'm wondering if there is an option to let it automatically cycle through each button while still allowing it to be interactive.

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aajv8mj5/)

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-calendar.png">
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-calendar.png'"><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Track use of the Teeter Inversion Table, including session length, frequency, and angle. </p>    </div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-trends.png'"><i class="fa fa-area-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Track your pain levels (pre and post inversion) and triggers. </p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-notifications.png'"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Set reminders/push notifications to use the Teeter.</p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-countdown.png'"><i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Turn on optional voice prompts from Roger Teeter, offering guidance and tips to ensure the best experience.  </p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-music.png'"><i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Select from a playlist of relaxing tunes while inverting. </p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-discover.png'"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Explore the Discover feed, offering helpful product use tips and healthy lifestyle advice.    </p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-support.png'"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Gain easy access to product support, videos, and contact information. </p></div>
<div style="display:table;"><button class="features-button-app" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-stories.png'"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Offer feedback, submit your own success story and join the Teeter community. </p></div>


     .features-button-app { 

    height: 66px;
   border-color: #ffffff;
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #a8c446;
height: 64px;
width: 64px;
line-height: 64px;
border-radius: 50%;
border-width: 0;
position: relative;
top: 1px;
left: 1px;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 32px;
float: left;
  margin-right: 29px;}

.features-button-app:active {
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #a8c446;
color: #a8c446;
   border-style: solid;}

.features-button-app:hover {
border-width: 1px;
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #a8c446;
color: #a8c446;
 border-style: solid;}

 .features-button-app:focus {
 border-width: 1px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: #a8c446;
color: #a8c446;
 border-style: solid;
     outline-color: transparent !important;}
.features-text-app {
line-height:1;
margin-top:0px; !important;
margin-bottom:15% !important;}
```

Comment: your buttons do not include type.  the default button type is submit. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: I really don't know a lot about javascript and the way this was built, so I didn't mean to do that on purpose. What should it be?

Comment: it seems redundant but <button class="features-button-app"   should be changed to <button type='button' class="features-button-app"

Comment: Good to know! I will have to research all the button types to make sure I know what I'm doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sample is not complete or efficient but it works and will give you an idea   It is set up to run through just once.

Html set up to call a function with an index number.

```
                <img id="myImage" src="http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-calendar.png">
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(0)"><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Track use of the Teeter Inversion Table, including session length, frequency, and angle. </p>    </div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(1)"><i class="fa fa-area-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Track your pain levels (pre and post inversion) and triggers. </p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(2)"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Set reminders/push notifications to use the Teeter.</p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(3)"><i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Turn on optional voice prompts from Roger Teeter, offering guidance and tips to ensure the best experience.  </p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(4)"><i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Select from a playlist of relaxing tunes while inverting. </p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(5)"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Explore the Discover feed, offering helpful product use tips and healthy lifestyle advice.    </p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button"class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(6)"><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app">Gain easy access to product support, videos, and contact information. </p></div>
                <div style="display:table;"><button type="button" class="features-button-app" onclick="setImage(7)"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> <p class="features-text-app"> Offer feedback, submit your own success story and join the Teeter community. </p></div>
```

image paths put in an array and a interval timer set.

```
             // each path put in an array to cycle through
                    var cimg = ['http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-calendar.png',
               'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-trends.png',
               'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-notifications.png',
               'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-countdown.png',
              'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-music.png',
               'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-discover.png',
              'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-support.png',
              'http://teetertv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/app-features-stories.png']

                    // gobal index used to keep track of where you are
                    var index = 0;

                    // turn on interval
                    var interval = setInterval(function () {
                        document.getElementById('myImage').src = cimg[index];
                        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[index++].focus();
                        if (index >= cimg.length) {
                            // all images seen so shut it off.
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    }, 3000)

                    // click event handler that will turn off the interval if user clicks on a button.
                    function setImage(num) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        document.getElementById('myImage').src = cimg[num];
                    }
```

Comment: Wow!! This is what I was hoping to achieve! I have two more questions that you don't really have to help with, only if you want to. Is there a way to cycle through it infinitely? Also, is there a way to fade transition between them?

Comment: Actually, I think cycling through once is just fine!! But having a fade into each one would be cool

Comment: I could but I would be coping someone else's effort.   Here is a link to a pure css solution with a working sample.   I took your list of images and pasted them in, then removed the width and height from their class and it started working.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313825/multiple-image-cross-fading-in-css-without-java-script

Comment: I noticed that when this element is put further down the page, it keeps jumping to that element on the page every interval no matter where you are on the page. Is there something I can do to let it start a cycle when they scroll to that part of the page, but not keep jumping back once it starts?

Comment: I noticed that too.  I did find this, it might be more help than I was. It provides formulas for figuring out the numbers.http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: Also, there are a number of slide show plugins that might make this easy for you

Comment: I was able to use one of the examples in the link you provided, but I can't figure out how to have both the automatic fade and the buttons to change the image. I know there are plug ins for a slider, I just wanted to be able to have more unique navigation buttons instead of a plain slider.

Comment: I am not sure where you are now since we have discussed several solutions but the bottom line is that you probably can remove the class that causes auto rotation and add the class that shows the current focus.

Comment: if you update jsFiddle, I can take another look at it tonight

Comment: So I have a few different versions that I am working with trying to find one that works. There's this one: https://jsfiddle.net/aajv8mj5/1/ which works great, but it jumps the page down.
I tried making one with the Demo 6 slider from the link you provided, however I can't make it auto rotate: https://jsfiddle.net/8k2hbcur/1/
I also tried some W3 schools tutorials, they have one with an auto rotate and one with buttons. I can get each one to work, I just can't figure out how to combine them: https://jsfiddle.net/fu5Lytu1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/3r6xde1d/.

Comment: Here's a link to the w3 schools page I was looking at: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aajv8mj5/1/ jumps because focus is changing to a lower and lower button.  Instead of using an actual focus you can add a focus class and just change class instead of focus

Comment: Would I need to change this line then?
 document.getElementsByTagName("button")[index++].focus();

Comment: no, you need to get complete away from using the focus function call unless it is triggered by the user.

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to research how to do that then.

Comment: i have actually done some stuff but it is not ready to show. I will try to get back to it to night (provided that to much beer does not interfere. It is Friday)

Comment: Oh! Wow, thank you! Well drink up! I probably won't get back to this until monday anyways. I really appreciate all your help

Comment: do you want straight javascript or is jquery and jquery ui available?

Comment: I'm not really sure. We're using wordpress for the page. It seems, in the head tag, we are linking to /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4" so Yes?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/p1jao3mw/24/  this one transitions better but the click event handler breaks it instead of activating it.  Think it has something to do with canceling the timer while the fade is in progress.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much. This is exactly what I visioned in my head but I didn't know how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, which specify a period to wait before executing a function or between successive executions of that function, respectively.

Comment: So how would I implement that into the code that I have?