# Background Crossfade

Tags: html, css, background, cross-fade

I am working on a [website](http://www.marcocarlo.com/mimosa/index.html) (early stages) and I'm having severe difficulties applying a background crossfade in the **white-background area** (I would like to have a few images auto-rotating on the background, completely filling it).

As per the HTML code, I should be fine working with class .main-container in the CSS however, this changes nothing...

I would sincerely appreciate your help, I'm self-taught in HTML+CSS and I just need guidance for the right steps to take.

What would you recommend?

Many thanks in advance!

(update)

I decided to go for the Tympanus.net solution.

Which has been badly implemented to http://www.marcocarlo.com/mimosa/index.html

Here's the CSS code:

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
    background-size:cover; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s; 
}
```

What can I do so it is on display in the white background area (fully covering it?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I don't see any styles for `.main-container` your CSS.

Comment: This might be what you're going for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8540921/968301

Comment: @Marcatectura there are no styles for .main-container, I tried adding them but nothing changes. I'll go for what Craig has outlined and will update you if I still get nowhere!

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking for some [existing guides](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/). Or maybe look for some existing image sliders with crossfade transitions. If you are willing to write your own crossfade though, you can use `background-size: cover` to fill entire areas ([example](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/))

Comment: Try adding some code and not just links, as the link(s) may become invalid.

Comment: @marcocarlo On your first style (.cb-slideshow, .cb-slideshow:after ), try setting z-index: -1. Tell me if that's what you want. There seems to be some readability issues also.

Comment: @EditName, thank you! That did the trick, may I ask you what that setting actually did so I just don't replicate but learn from it? Now I need to add some background with transparency to the css class 'main wrapper clearfix' and that has been a challenge on it's own. Is that the readability issue you're mentioning or do I need to look elsewhere? Many many thanks!

Comment: @EditName, I just realised it's also making the page wider than it should, which looks funny... do I need to fix the height and weight differently?

Comment: @marcocarlo z-index is the stacking order of the elements. 0 is usually where things start off. A smaller the z-index means the element is closer to the bottom of the stack. [Look at this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) for more info. Yeah, adding a background below 'main wrapper clearfix' would potentially make the text more readable.

Comment: @marcocarlo You need to set `margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;` on your first style (`.cb-slideshow, .cb-slideshow:after` ). The reason it's stretching is there's automatic margin and padding added to <ul> tags depending on your browser.

Comment: @EditName, I am now having problems with the transparency... It sets all text within it to the same transparency. Would you know a quick turnaround to this as none of the similar cases I've found on the site really solve the problem? Thank you!