# Transition on 5 images

Tags: html, css

I'm given the following task,

**Actual html which I have:** Two images are stacked on top of each other.(below html) when the user hovers on the foreground image, as per the CSS rules opacity will be transitioned to 0 in 4 seconds and this keeps happening in a cycle.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQf5q/1/)**

**Modification I have to do:** Now I have to perform the same for 5 images.  I've tried doing the same as below, could not succeed(See second code snippet). Any hints as to how this can be done only using **css** ? thanks

**[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/3F7eM/1/)**

```
 <!-- Melting one image into another using CSS3. -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Melting Images</title>
<style type = "text/css">
 #cover
 {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #cover img
 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
 }
 #cover img.top:hover
 { opacity:0; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id = "cover">
 <img class = "bottom" src = "jhtp.png" alt = "Java 9e cover">
 <img class = "top" src = "jhtp8.png" alt = "Java 8e cover">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What I've tried

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Melting Images</title>
<style type = "text/css">
 #cover
 {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #cover img
 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 4s ease-in-out;
 }
 #cover img.top:hover
 { opacity:0; }

 #cover img.top1:hover
 { opacity:0; }

 #cover img.top2:hover
 { opacity:0; }

 #cover img.top3:hover
 { opacity:0; }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id = "cover">
 <img class = "bottom" src = "jhtp.png" alt = "Java 9e cover">
 <img class = "top" src = "jhtp8.png" alt = "Java 8e cover">
 <img class = "top1" src = "jhtp1.png" alt = "Java 8e cover">
 <img class = "top2" src = "jhtp2.png" alt = "Java 8e cover">
 <img class = "top3" src = "jhtp3.png" alt = "Java 8e cover">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could create a fiddle on an online demo.

Comment: Maybe you could do it with the keyframes.

Comment: fiddle? i'm completely new to css and html. I've worked on other thick clients though.

Comment: @Zeus Sorry, we thought you knew what a fiddle was.  In SO, a fiddle is unofficially considered a [jsfiddle](http://JSFiddle.net) project.

Comment: I just tried fiddle, no luck with images though, i've tried to use some external images. Looks like it is not showing up.

Comment: Hey guys, ive updated the fiddle links. You may want to have a look. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [css3 image crossfade (no javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540906/css3-image-crossfade-no-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that only in CSS, and applying the styles to the container and the children, whatever this are.

I have set an example using div as children, but you can modify it to whatever you want

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
    <div class="item4">4</div>
    <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.container div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 60px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover div {
    -webkit-animation: anim 5s infinite; 
    animation: anim 5s infinite; 
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}
.container div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.container div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.container div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    0%, 15% {opacity: 1;}
    20%, 95% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes anim {
    0%, 15% {opacity: 1;}
    20%, 95% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rw79/)

Answer (score 0):

As hovering is a binary process (you're either hovering an element or you're not), I'm afraid this is not possible with CSS only. You write some JS code that will be also triggeren on hover and that will take care of replacing images below and sorting them. However, that seems like an ugly mishmash.

Maybe you could do it using keyframes, but again, you'd need a way to trigger an animation for each image. I'm talking about building a 20s animation for each image and then modifying the opacity value for each in 4 second intervals. But again, seems like too much effort.

So, I'd **strongly** suggest you write a simple JS image fader that will handle both the image sorting and fade animations at a slight cost of performance.

If you still want to use as much CSS as possible, go with the keyframes, and set a JS listener on the container element which will add a class to each image - that class would trigger the CSS animation for each image. You'll have to repeat the first image and put it at the bottom. The animation would make the 1st image transparent by the second 4, 2nd image by second 8, etc...